# Why is my basic Ajax script not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, file-get-contents

I have been playing around with Javascript and now I came to Ajax. I am trying to write very simple script that would get the file contents - print the `txt` file contents in the `div` with `id=test`. This is the script :

```
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET" , url ,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
}
```

when I use it on this website :

```
<div id="test"  name="test"> HELLo </div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('test1.txt')">ClickMe1</button>
```

With this script `HELLo` is substituted by nothing - the script empties the container.

Maybe I am missing something trivial but do I need PHP installed ? I don't think so but... I am not sure what is happening in here. When I am debugging the `xmlhttp` is empty the whole time. Why ?

Comment: I would suggest using a framework, such as JQuery for ajax, it automatically handles a lot of the inconsistencies between different browser and even same browser but different versions.

Comment: @ClydeLobo As I have discovered just now - my `xmlhttp.status` is the whole time `0`. Why is it like this ? I should get `200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For browsers other than IE**

IE's active X object seems not to care much about the ready state, other browsers may not have the text loaded quickly enough at the time you run your function (hence why you are getting the blank instead of file contents).  IE's active X seems to handle this automatically and ignores the ready state, so you have to break up the code differently as below.  Normally you check the `status` of the request to see if it's been fully read or not before accessing the `responseText`.

Add `onreadystatechange` you *cannot* check the `status` attribute since there is no HTTP requests being made on a *file system* request.  (The status will always be 0 for request not made via HTTP) The best I can offer is this:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
       xmlhttp.open( "GET", url );
       xmlhttp.send(null);

    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

       xmlhttp.open( "GET", url );
       xmlhttp.send(null);
       document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

}
```

**For CHROME**

If you are using **CHROME** you must start chrome up with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch.  Otherwise, it will refuse *file system* ajax requests.  (You will have to set this even if using a so-called "easier" library such as jQuery).

**Running AJAX apps on File System In General**

Not usually a good idea, a lot of caveats to this route.  Typically local development is done with a web server installed to localhost on your development machine.

Comment: If you can tell me what OS and browser (and version) you are using I can try to help you out further to get a working version.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 (64 bit) and Opera 11.61.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to check for readyState and the HTTP response status before replacing the text;

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

example on http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I have tried this and : while debugging I have discovered that my `xmlhttp.status` is the whole time `0`. What is wrong here then ?

Comment: Are you trying to make any cross domain request...you do not seem to be getting the response back for the request u make..

Comment: I am doing everything on the local machine - as stated before without any web server.

Comment: Oh ok..so can u try it on diff browsers...coz locally AJAX is not supported in all the browsers..it needs an http protocol...

Answer (score 0):

Today its old fashion to call ajax like xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

You have many other options for this.

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to fight with [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

A simple working code for a synchronous request is following:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (req.status == 200 && req.readyState == 4) {
    ...
}

req.open('GET', url, true);
req.send(null);
```

Note this is working for Firefox/Opera/Chrome. If IE, use:

```
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: I have also tried this - asynchronous request - it didn't work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try with jQuery. Download the last version [here](http://jquery.com/) and write this code snippet:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url) {   
  $("#test").load(url);
}
```

It's much simpler and less error prone

Answer (score -1):

You need a server to listen up to requests. Your regular file system will not be able to respond to AJAX requests.

You don't need PHP, however you'll need apache or a similar web server.

Comment: I think I do not need a server but if I am wrong please correct me.